# Should I pay up the rest of my tuition?

Tags: fees, tuition

I'm from a third world country sponsored by my government to study in Canada. I messed up my last year and my full scholarship was revoked, so I had to repeat a whole year with my own money. You won't believe how much I have to pay as an international student just for 2 semesters.

Fast forward, after I graduated and a couple month of unemployment, I manage to land a good job in my country with my audit (transcript and diploma held by the uni until I fully pay tuition fees). But the tuition fees are still a lot due to the conversion rate.

So now, I don't know what should I do. They (the university) will throw away my cert and transcript in one year. Should I pay up the fees which I had to take loan at my country bank when I could use it to buy property?

I know it is immoral to not pay debt but when you are in third world country, immoral is least my concern. I might even fake my certificate just in case I want to change jobs, which is unlikely.

Comment: Do you really want to mess up again? Apparently you did not learn the first time.

Comment: IT doesn't make sense for the university to destroy your transcripts if you don't pay. Destroying the transcripts removes all reason to pay because w/o transcripts to get there is no reason to give them the money.

Answer (score 11):

You can't seriously be asking to be put at ease to not pay fees due (additionally, to who might be the employer of some members of this site), or to counterfeit your diploma. Given the tone of your question, I assume you might be trolling; but if not, the answer is:

Yes, you should pay up the rest of your tuition.

No, you should not fake your diploma.